# How to redirect stdout & stdin to telnet connection?

Tags: linux, console, stdout

I am running embedded linux program, so that the kernel init script automatically start the program, and the stdin/stdout are going through the serial device, which is also the shell.
When I connect to target with telnet, I don't see the same stdin/stdout of the program.

Maybe I can redirect console stdin/stdout to telnet connection ?

What ways do I have to gain such capabilities using the telnet connection ?

Thanks,
Ran

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Hi Ignacio, thanx for the remark, I've edited the question again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible with telnet, but you can mock it through netcat. Just like below:

```
<STDOUT> | netcat -t www.example.com 80
```

Comment: thanks, do you think it's possible to enter the above from the telnet connection or should it be done from the serial ?

Comment: what about stdin, is it also redirected to netcat ?